# Is it possible to change MasterViewController width for SplitView?

Tags: iphone, uisplitviewcontroller

How to change the split view MasterViewController width for iPad?

Is it possible to use UIView instead of UITableView on the MAsterViewController?

Apple support for these two?

Please explain. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use UIView and can assign whatever size to that view, and inside that UIView you can put UITableView.

Happy Coding!!!!!!

Comment: Thank you. How to change the master view width.